# Match the GPS coordinates with the pixel from the map image in flutter

Tags: flutter, image, dart, gps, coordinates

[image]

I have the actual data:

1. I have a map image (So I know the number of pixels in each direction and I can get the central pixel)
2. I have the central GPS coordinate of the map image.

now there are so many other GPS coordinates that I need to calculate and show on the map image.

Is there any package to support such a thing?
if not, how should I calculate the location(pixel) of other coordinates on the map image?

Comment: did you take a look at [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter)

Comment: @rashidotm thanks for your comment, [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) is not capable of doing such a thing. I don't want to use Google Maps.

Comment: but why don't you use the map and instead using a picture?

Comment: @rashidotm There are several existing designed map images I have to work on them.

Comment: If the number is manageable then I would rather rework with a map rather than a picture.

Comment: @rashidotm As I mentioned, they are designed map images.